# GIMP install failed by ubuntu-software and also "sudo snap install gimp"

Tags: software-installation, snap, gimp

I get the following error while trying to install gimp either through Ubuntu-software of Terminal:

***error: snap "gimp" has "install-snap" change in progress***

When I run the command "snap changes". It displays:

***ID   Status  Spawn               Ready  Summary***

***30   Doing   today at 16:23 IST  -      Install "gimp" snap***

I searched there is no gimp process with id as 30.
Rebooted the computer but nothing worked.
I am a novice to ubuntu and Linux environment.
what should I do? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID is not the ID of a process, but the ID of a failed snap install. Please do

```
sudo snap abort 30 && sudo systemctl restart snapd.service
```

Then, try reinstalling.
BTW, there are two no-snap ways to install GIMP; by Flatpak or Ubuntu's repositories. The latter is:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gimp
```

and the flatpak method is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak && sudo apt update && sudo apt install flatpak 
flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
```

Comment: You could also just install from the repos without the PPA.  18.04 has version 2.8.22-1

Comment: @OrganicMarble 2.8.22 is quite obsolete, 2.10 is really life-changing in many aspects.

Comment: @Organic Marble Is GIMP in the repos a snap? Wanted to offer a snap-free alternative.

Comment: No, it's a regular install. But I don't use any of the 'software centers', just `sudo aptitude install`